# Maximum value of the largest interior angle in a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the three interior angles of a triangle, where $a\leq b \leq c$. It is given that $4c = 7a$. Find the maximum possible value of $c$, i.e. the largest interior angle.

The question is now maximizing $c$ with the constraints

- $a+b+c=180$
- $a\leq b \leq c$
- $4c = 7a$

I try to consider $a = \frac47 c$ but I have no idea how to proceed. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: The question can be re-interpreted as *Finding the smallest value of* $\angle a $ and $\angle b $ ,  where you are given $a\le b \le c$ and $7c = 4a$ . Doesn't this provides any useful insight now ?

Comment: I would write$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^{\circ}$$ $$\alpha\le \beta\le \gamma$$ and $$4\gamma=7\alpha$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also write $b$ in terms of $c$:

$$b = 180 - a - c = 180 -\frac47c - c = 180 -\frac{11}7c.$$

So you need to find the largest value of $c$ that does not violate

$$\frac47c \leqslant 180 -\frac{11}7c \leqslant c.$$

Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: My attempt: The compound inequality can be rewritten into two parts. $\frac47 c \leq 180 - \frac{11}{7}c$ implies $c\leq 84$. $180 - \frac{11}{7}c \leq c$ implies $c \geq 70$. Combining these two results, we have the maximum value as 84. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct, yes!